# Concurrent requests Flask python

Tags: python, flask

I have some `Flask` application. It works with some database, I'm using `SQLAlchemy` for this. So I have one question:

Flask handle requests one-by-one. So, for example, I have two users, which are modifying the same record in the table of database, for example A and B (they are concurrent).

How can I say to user B that user A has changed this record? It must be some message to user B.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the development server version, when you do `app.run()`, you get a single synchronous process, which means at most 1 requests being processed at a time. So you cannot accept multiple users at the same time.

However, [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) is a solid, easy-to-use [WSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) server that will let you spawn multiple workers (separate processes), and even comes with asynchronous workers when you need to deploy your application.

However, to answer your question, since, they run on separate threads, the data that exists in the database at the specific time when the query is run in that thread will be used/returned.

I hope this answers your query.

Comment: I don't know how do this.